# How to do getWritableDatabase() in asyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have been doing my database transactions on the UI thread and it've working without any noticeable UI freezing because the database is small, but I am worried because database transactions are not supposed to be done on the UI thread.

I found here on SO that AsyncTask is the best solution for solving this but I didn't see a practical example. And moreover I have never used the Asynctask class.

This is the method I call from `onCreateView` of the fragment:

```
private void getBookDb () {
        Log.d(TAG, "getBookDb called");
        mDatabase = mBookHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + BookEntry.NAME, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                BookItem bookItem = new BookItem();
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BookEntry.ID));
                String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BookEntry.URL));

                bookItem.setProductId(id);
                bookItem.setUrl(url);
            }

            bottomRoot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Database is empty");
            emptyRoot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        mDatabase.close();
        mBookAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mBookAdapter.getItemCount());
}
```

Please can you show me how to do this in AsyncTask?

Comment: you just need to call `getBookDb ()` from the async `doInBackground` that should work i have a similar thing on the app and it works perfectly

Comment: @TiagoOliveira I am updating the UI thread in `getBookDb()`. Is calling it from `doInBackground`, a good idea? I thought we are not supposed to update the UI thread from`doInBackground`?

Comment: you collect and return the data in `doInBackground`  and you update the UI in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 2):

1) AsyncTask isn't difficult, Google it and there are plenty of tutorials.

2) Once you understand AsyncTask, put your call to `getBookDb()` into the AsyncTask's `doInBackground()` method.

3) Try to refactor your code so you don't have to update any UI elements until `doInBackground()` ends and the call to `onPostExecute()` is made, and then do all your UI updating in the `onPostExecute()` method, which runs on the UI thread. Also, you can update UI in the `onPreExecute()` method, so try to do all your UI stuff in the `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` .. but ..

4) If you have to you can actually update UI elements while in the AsyncTask's `doInBackground()` method by using this code:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // Runs in the UI thread
                }
            });
```

5) In addition, I believe that the better, safer, and "proper" way to put/read information in a SQLite db is to use `ContentValues` rather than `rawQuery()`, as shown here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#WriteDbRow